# Codeigniter SERVER ERROR 500 while login application

Tags: php, codeigniter, server

I have create application on codeigniter this is my first application. I have uploaded on hosting server. Basic website is working fine but when I move to login application I am getting server error 500. and I cant fill the forms also after submitting it getting same error.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: First check your class and file names make sure you only have the first letter upper case.

Comment: Yes All classes having uppercase letters i have checked...

Comment: Are you using URL rewriting? If yes, post your .htaccess file here.

Comment: yes using         <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a database issue, make sure your database credentials are correct in /application/config/database.php.